# LINQ update and select

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is it possible to perform a select and update statement on a database in the same LINQ query using VB.NET?
For example

```
From message In db.Messages Where message.MessageID = messageId And message.To = userid 
Select message   ... and message.read = true
```

Comment: Do you use entity framework?

Comment: well it might be possible to put it into one statement but under the hood at least two queries to db will be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can't do this in SQL either.

What you can do is write a stored procedure to run the update and return the select together. Then hide the Messages table so no-one other than the sproc can query it. Use EF to call the sproc and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
(From message In db.Messages
Where message.MessageID = messageId And message.To = userid 
Select message).ToList().Foreach(Function(m) m.read = true);
```

This cannot be used with databases though.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified it was for use on a database